# What is the best way to auto subscribe new Salesforce Contacts in MobileConnect?

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, mobileconnect, sms

I want to automatically subscribe new Contacts in Service Cloud in Mobile Connect to a particular keyword. How can I do this?

I could potentially query all contacts and do mobileconnect import, but the problem with this is that I may overwrite any existing opt out statuses for existing subscribers of the keyword (in case they've opted out).

From what I know there is no way to query a data view to see existing opt outs and exclude them from my original query.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275784/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-subscribe-new-salesforce-contacts-in-mobileconnect